# I need to make a post request in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, post

I am new to networking in a flutter.
The method type is POST
I have path and headers.
I also have one variable of a class type in it.

Answer (score 0):

add dependency in your pubspec.yaml file
dependencies:
http: <latest_version>

import it
import 'package:http/http.dart' as HTTP;

Sending data to the server

```
Future<http.Response> createAlbum(String title) {
  return http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'title': title,
    }),
  );
}
```

you can also use Postman for API creation and checking connection or data from app to server, also postman gives you the sample code and it also provide code for dart